# Go to definition from text position with roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, go-to-definition

How to get file name and position of definition of any symbol under the current custom position and file (within project or solution)?

I do the following steps (simplified explanation):

1. Create collection of syntax trees and compilation by the following way:

   ```
   SyntaxTrees = new List<SyntaxTree>();
   foreach (var file in projectFiles)
       syntaxTrees.Add(SyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(file));
   Compilation = Compilation.Create("temp.cs", null, SyntaxTrees, new MetadataReference[] { mscorlib });
   ```
2. Get current token in syntax tree:

   ```
   var token = currentTree.GetRoot().FindToken(textPos, false);
   ```

Symbol have appropriate method for definition getting: `DeclaringSyntaxNodes`.
How can I resolve `token` on `Symbol` in `SemanticModel`? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [`SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPosition` method](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder.cs,956940438af1fdee).